# What happens when two applications on the same host communicate via sockets?

Tags: sockets, udp, stack

I have application A and application B running on a host.

Application A sends to Application B using a UDP message.

I'd assume it does not go out the Network Card, but how far down the TCP/IP stack does it go?

Is there any advantage to doing this over a Unix Domain Socket?

Can you send a UDP message to your own IP address and just have each application listen on different ports?

Answer (score 0):

> how far down the TCP/IP stack does it go?

Usually it reaches IP layer, but sometimes it depends. (See [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wincat/2012/12/05/fast-tcp-loopback-performance-and-low-latency-with-windows-server-2012-tcp-loopback-fast-path/), only TCP though.)

> Is there any advantage to doing this over a Unix Domain Socket?

Yes, it's very common to use Unix Domain Socket instead for better performance.

> Can you send a UDP message to your own IP address and just have each
>   application listen on different ports?

Yes we can.